# SELECT only where no row matches

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need a query that will be able to disinguish when a Name is "uncategorised"

eg

```
+---------+------+------+
|Full Name|Cat_ID|Option|
+---------+------+------+
|John Doe |1     |1     |
|John Doe |2     |0     |
|John Doe |3     |0     |
|Jane Doe |1     |0     |
|Jane Doe |2     |0     |
|Jane Doe |3     |0     |
+---------+------+------+
```

I need a query that will get Jane Doe, because no option = 1 of all the categories.
Uforunately, as all Names have a 0 at least 1 category, I'm end up extracting everyone.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fullname
FROM    tablename
WHERE   fullname NOT IN
        (
            SELECT  a.FullName
            FROM    tablename a
            WHERE   a.option = 1
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea522/2)

Another way is by using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT aa.Fullname
FROM    tablename aa
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.FullName
            FROM    tablename a
            WHERE   a.option = 1
        ) bb ON aa.Fullname = bb.Fullname
WHERE   bb.Fullname IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea522/5)

I'll prefer to use `JOIN` over `NOT IN`. For better performance, define an `INDEX` on column `FullName`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative approach.

```
SELECT `fullName`
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `fullName`
HAVING SUM(`option`)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe? (probably not the most efficient, but should work)

```
SELECT full_name FROM table WHERE full_name NOT IN (SELECT full_name FROM table WHERE option=1);
```